# How to customize ion-range in ionic 5?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ion-range-slider

I am looking for a solution with my current issue regarding on how to customize the `ion-range` based on the wireframe. As you can see below the difference between the wireframe and the actual worked I made.

**Wireframe Design**

[image: wireframe]

**My actual work**

[image]

Above, you can see the difference between the two. My question is, is there anyway or solution that I can do to get the actual look of the wireframe. Based on the wireframe, as the user moves the tick, the label aligned with the tick should be color blue also.

These are my codes I used and produced my actual work.

**.html**

```
   <div class="slidecontainer">
    <ion-range 
        class="range-position"
        min="5" 
        max="100" 
        dualknobs="true"
        pin="false"
        snaps="true"
        ticks="false"
        value="0" 
        snaps color="primary"
        list='tickmarks'>
    </ion-range>

    <div id="tickmarks" class="tick-position">
        <p>5</p>
        <p>10</p>
        <p>25</p>
        <p>50</p>
        <p>75</p>
        <p>100</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**.scss**

```
// Customize Slider
   #tickmarks {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding: 0 25px;
   }

   #tickmarks p {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1px;
    background: #ccd3da;
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    font-family: 'Archivo';
    font-size: 12px;
   }
```

Hope you can help so that I can move forward with my task. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can Use `(ionChange)` event to make it work.

```
 <ion-range 
    class="range-position"
    min="5" 
    max="100" 
    dualknobs="true"
    pin="false"
    snaps="true"
    ticks="false"
    value="0"
    step="25"  // use step attribute for sure event value
    snaps color="primary"
    list='tickmarks'
    (ionChange)="changeFunction($event)">
</ion-range>
<div id="tickmarks" class="tick-position">
    <p [ngClass]="selectedValue == 0 ? 'active' : null">5</p>
    <p [ngClass]="selectedValue == 25 ? 'active' : null">25</p>
    <p [ngClass]="selectedValue == 50 ? 'active' : null">50</p>
    <p [ngClass]="selectedValue == 75 ? 'active' : null">75</p>
    <p [ngClass]="selectedValue == 100 ? 'active' : null">100</p>
</div>
```

.ts

```
selectedValue;

changeFunction($event){
   this.selectedValue =  $event.detail.value;
}
```

Comment: that solution will work.Logic will play like show hide concept.

Comment: @Anuj No, it will just change CSS classes to highlight selected values. using `ngClass` or `ngStyle` you can dynamically set css styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the the tick marks underneath the `ion-range` component react to the selected value in the range, like below.

Add a function that listens to the `ionChange` event to `<ion-change>`. Use that function in your component class to update a value. Then you can use that value in your template to indicate which tick should be highlighted (gets the `selected` CSS class).

`range.component.html` - for single range (one knob)

```html
<div class="range-container">
  <ion-range
    (ionChange)="setValue($event)"        
    [value]="currentValue" 
    color="primary"
    dual-knobs="false"
    max="100"
    min="0"
    pin="false"
    snaps="true"
    step="25"
    ticks="false"
    
  >
  </ion-range>
  <ul class="tick-marks">
    <li 
      *ngFor="let number of [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]"
      [class.selected]="number === currentValue"
    >
      {{number}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`range.component.html` - for dual knobs

```html
<div class="range-container">
  <ion-range
    (ionChange)="setDualValues($event)"
    [value]="currentDualValues" 
    color="primary"
    dual-knobs="true"
    max="100"
    min="0"
    pin="false"
    snaps="true"
    step="25"
    ticks="false"
  >
  </ion-range>
  <ul class="tick-marks">
    <li 
      *ngFor="let number of [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]"
      [class.selected]="number === currentDualValues.lower || number === currentDualValues.upper"
    >
      {{number}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`range.component.ts`- the component file

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-range',
  styleUrls: ['./range.component.scss']
  templateUrl: './range.component.html'
})
export class RangeComponent {
  currentValue = 0;
  currentDualValues = {
    lower: 25,
    upper: 50
  };
  
  // use this for single slider
  setValue($event: Event): void {
    this.currentValue = parseInt(($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value, 10);
  }
  
  // use this for dual sliders (dual knobs)
  setDualValues($event: Event): void {
    this.currentDualValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
  }
}
```

Finally, in your CSS add the `.selected` class to style selected numbers as you wish, for instance like this (you will probably need to change padding of `ul.tick-marks` to make sure the tick marks align properly with the range selector):

`range.component.scss`

```css
.range-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;

  .tick-marks {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    li {
      color: var(--ion-color-dark);
      position: relative;

      &::before {
        background-color: var(--ion-color-dark);
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        top: -20px;
      }

      &.selected {
        color: var(--ion-color-primary);

        &::before {
          background-color: var(--ion-color-primary); 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See also this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ion-range-custom-tickmarks?file=src/app/range/range.component.ts) for reference.